# match query with regex and send to 404

Tags: php

Google keeps inputing crap into my forms and searching and ending up with 0 result pages and is indexing them.
Google has been searching stuff like this

```
0 0 41 1 0 0 9 1 0â€ž3ï¿½Â¨7 0 0 0â€ž3ï¿½Ã¬7;7 0 6 0 674 0 0 70 555
```

I have no clue why google would search for that. I have read online that google will input random crap and words it finds on pages into forms but Google is indexing this crap and I want it to stop.

Google has searched for random crap like this thousands of time for a few months now. I hoped it would stop but it hasn't. Most of the searches start with the number 0.

So what I would like to do is make it so if any search is done with a 0 for the start of the query, send it to a 404.

I need something like this I am guessing. 
Example code:

> if($_GET["query"] == "/Regular expression here/")
>   header("Location: 404 page");

Does anyone know how I can match any query starting with the number 0 and then send it to a 404? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this...

You could do...

```
if (substr(trim($_GET["query"]), 0, 1) == '0') {
   // Send 404.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, in this case this is much more efficient. But regular expressions would allow more flexible extension of this method to other "excluded patterns" without changing most of the code..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using PERL regex, so preg_match()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Maybe something like

```
if(preg_match('/^0/', $_GET["query"])>0)
   header("Location: 404 page");
```